# How to subtract input values

Tags: jquery, phpmyadmin

i have a php page where i would be able to subtract two values from which one is fetched from mysql database and another one is entered by user itself. What i want exactly is while entering the value in second input field the entered value should be subtracted from first input value calling from database and the subtracted value should be visible in another input...
Code is...

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <style>
            td {font-size:13px;}
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){           
              $('input').each(function() {
                    $(this).keyup(function(){  
                         calculatedis($(this));
                      });
                });
           });

          function calculatedis(src) {
          var sub = 0;
          var sumtable = src.closest('.sumtable');
          sumtable.find('input').each(function() {
                var amt1 = $('input[name="amt1"]').val();
                var amt2 = $('input[name="amt2"]').val();
                sub = (amt1 - amt2)
              });
          sumtable.find(".netAmt").val(sub.toFixed(2));
          }   
         </script> 
      </head>
      <body>
         <form class="inward">
         <?php
            include("dbconnection.php");
            $sql = "SELECT id,price FROM table1 WHERE id='3' ORDER BY id";
            $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' class='sumtable'>";

             echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC' height='30'>";
            echo "<td>Price</td>";
            echo "<td>Discounted Amt</td>";
            echo "<td>Net Amt</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
            while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
            {
            //change row color alternately  
            $i++;
            $color = ($i%2) ? "#f8f8ff" : "#f0fff0";
            echo "<tr bgcolor=" . $color . " onmouseover='ChangeBackgroundColor(this)' onmouseout='RestoreBackgroundColor(this)'>
                $price = $row2["price"];
            if (strlen(trim($price)) == 0)
            {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<td valign='top'><input name='amt1' value=" . $price . " size='5'/></td>";
            }
            echo "<td valign='top' ><input name='amt2' size='5'/></td>";
            echo "<td valign='top'><input  name='netamt' class='netAmt' size='5'/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<tr><td></td></tr>";
            echo "<center>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type='reset' name='clear' value='Clear' style='cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;'>";
            echo "</center>";

         ?>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Don't Know what's wrong with this any kind of help would be appreciated............

In addition to this.....can i get the sum of these subtracted values at the end of loop like Total is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through every `input`, but then doing a calculation into sub that is discarded each time. Try looping through each `tr` instead.

Also, you need to wrap your `$('input[name=..]').val()` with a call to parseInt() (or, if non-integer, an equivalent). With the code as it is, it's retrieving their values as strings. Try:

```
sumtable.find('tr').each(function() {
    var amt1 = parseInt($(this).find('input[name="amt1"]').val());
    var amt2 = parseInt($(this).find('input[name="amt2"]').val());
    sub = (amt1 - amt2)
    $(this).find('.netAmt').val(sub);
});
```

Comment: @Andrian thanx fr ur kind help, i hv tried ths up but NaN is displaying in netAmt input where the subtracted value should come...

Comment: Have values been added in for both textboxes? NaN is 'not a number'; parseInt() on a blank string will return this, and adding NaN to another number will too.

Comment: oops....sorry man i forgot to include ; in  $(this).find('.netAmt').val(sub) may be thats why i was getting NaN but thank u buddy bcoz of ur tr looping suggestion my script running perfectly......